# FORTRAN: Setting array to 0 won't work

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am doing something I've done time after time, setting an array to zero in Fortran 90. However, for some reason in this case it is not working, and I have no idea why.

I allocate the array and use `A = 0.d0` but when I write out one of the components it prints as 0.4xxx

My array is a module-level array if this makes any difference, and I am initializing it within a subroutine.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?

EDIT: Sorry I have been away therefore haven't responded. This is still happening. I am using gfortran 4.3. I have changed a few things to see if they will help but they haven't. Notice below that I set the elements to zero **two ways**. Within the loop they are definitely being set to zero, but after the loop at least one element is becoming non-zero for no apparent reason. I know that all other elements are non-zero as well. I changed the array concerned to be a local subroutine array but this has no effect. The following is the code that is giving me wrong output:

```
subroutine coeff_cube(f, Ng,x_max_8,coeffs)
  integer, intent(in)   :: Ng
  real(8), intent(in)   :: f(Ng,Ng,Ng)
  real(8), intent(in)   :: x_max_8


  integer               :: i,j,k,ii,jj,kk

  real(8)                :: Ints(Ng,nmax+1)
  real(8), intent(out)  :: coeffs(nmax+1,nmax+1,nmax+1)

  call cube_ints(x_max_8,Ng,Ints)

  write(*,*) "NOW NMAX IS: ", nmax       !Prints '24'
  coeffs = 0.0d0
  do i=1,nmax+1
    do j=1,nmax+1
      do k=1,nmax+1
        coeffs(i,j,k) = 0.d0
        write(*,*) coeffs(i,j,k)  !Prints 0.0000000000000000 for all i,j,k
      end do
    end do
  end do

  write(*,*) coeffs(1,3,28)               !Prints a non-zero number
  coeffs(1,3,28) = 0.0d0
  write(*,*) coeffs(1,3,28)               !Prints 0.0000000000000000

  do k=1,nmax+1
    i=1
    j=1
    if (i+j+k .GT. nmax+1)then
            exit
    end if
    do j=1,nmax+1
        i=1
        if (i+j+k .GT. nmax+1)then
            exit
        end if
      do i=1,nmax+1
        if (i+j+k .GT. nmax+1)then
            exit
        end if
        do kk=1,Ng
          do jj = 1,Ng
            do ii = 1,Ng
                coeffs(i,j,k) = coeffs(i,j,k) + &
                & f(ii,jj,kk)*Ints(ii,i)*Ints(jj,j)*Ints(kk,k)
                if(i==1.AND.j==3.AND.k==28)then
                    if (kk==1) then
                    write(*,*) coeffs(i,j,k)
                    end if
                end if
            end do
          end do
        end do
      end do
    end do
  end do
  write(*,*) coeffs(1,3,28)          !Prints 0.0000000000000000
end subroutine
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Show the code that allocates the array.

Comment: Are you sure that the element you try to write out is actually within the bounds of the array, i.e. the index is not too small or too large?

Comment: With this info we can only guess.  We need to see more code including declarations.   Is the print statement statement that shows the wrong value immediately after the initialization or later?  If later perhaps you have mistakenly written to the memory location, e.g., via a subscript error on another array.   I suggest using as many warning options of your compiler as possible, including run-time subscript checking.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: How does the subroutine get the value of `nmax` ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I have figured it out...

It does in fact set the array to zero, however for some reason I am writing an element that is not in the array (out of bounds). I would have expected it to give me an error rather than write out any old thing, but I guess that's just fortran...

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran

There are some compiler options for bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you can initialize an entire array with a single statement?

```
coeffs = 0.0d
```

will set all elements of the array to 0.

Comment: Have you actually read the code ?  In particular the 10th line ?

Comment: @Jerome - I am aware of that - you will notice that I do that in the code on the 10th line. In particular, I initialize the entire array with two differing methods (single statement and loop), each of which does not finally work. I also initialize a single element and that works, but only for that element. There is no question of me manually initializing each element since there are generally over a million elements.